# Dictionary with Multiple Keys for a Single Value - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm attempting to create an application that maps English letters to various RNA codons (sequences of A, C, U, or G in groups of 3), according to a predetermined mapping.

To convert from English to RNA, the dictionary looks like this:

```
var englishTomRNA: [Character: [String]] = ["A": ["UUU", "UAC"],
                                            "Q": ["UUA"],
                                            "S": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA"]]
```

etc.

As you can see, there are multiple values for any given English character (representing the biological characteristic of a polygenetic genotype), of which I have no issue converting to.

What I do have an issue implementing, however, is the dictionary to covert the other way. I originally used `switch: case` statements like so:

```
    for codon in preEnglishInputString {
        switch codon {
            case "UUU", "UAC":               inEnglish.append("A")
            case "UUA":                      inEnglish.append("Q")
            case "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG": inEnglish.append("S")
        }
    }
```

However, now I wish to convert the RNA -> English conversion function to use dictionaries to be more inline with this implementation.

I cannot figure out how to have multiple keys for a single value (the reverse of having multiple values for a single key, as used above.)

The following, when attempted, doesn't work:

```
let mRNAtoEnglish: [[String] : Character] =
                                            [["UUU", "UAC"]       : "A",
                                            ["UUA", "UUG"]        : "Q",
                                            ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA"] : "S"]
```

with the compiler yelling `Type [String] does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`

Am I simply using the wrong data structure, or is there some syntax that i'm not aware of? (I'm fairly new to Swift)

Thanks!

Comment: just save 3 keys with the same value instead of a single array with 3 keys

Comment: @LeoDabus see luiyezheng's answer + my comment for an update!

Comment: see my comment at James answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Swift's higher order functions:

```
var englishTomRNA: [Character: [String]] = ["A": ["UUU", "UAC"],
                                            "Q": ["UUA"],
                                            "S": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA"]]
var inEnglish = ""

// Sample Input
let preEnglishInputString = ["UUA", "UCC", "UUU"]

for codon in preEnglishInputString {
    let english = englishTomRNA
                        .filter { $0.1.contains(codon) }
                        .first!.0
    inEnglish.append(english)
}

print(inEnglish) // QSA
```

This works with 2 assumptions:

1. Each codon code is mapped to exactly 1 English character
2. Every codon code in `preEnglishInputString` is valid and can be found in your `englishTomRNA` dictionary.

---

### What it does:

`.filter { ... }` finds any key-value pair that contains the `codon`. When you call `filter` on a Dictionary, it degenereates into a tuple of `(key, value)` so `$0.1` refers to the `value`. `filter` always return an array of matches, even if it finds only one match.

`first!` gets the first match from the list (assumption 1). The exclamation  mark assumes that a match is always found (assumption 2).

`.0` gets the key of the key-value pair, which the English character.

Comment: If you are calling this on long strings of codons, the repeated filtering will take a lot of time. luiyezhang's dictionary-based answer will perform much better and expends a negligible amount of memory for the time it saves.

Comment: Your array of codon has to be *really* long, like a million or so, for the execution time to make a difference. Even then, I would rather make the `mRNAtoEnglish` in code rather than typing in a new literal dictionary

Comment: See my answer for making the dictionary programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use array for a Dictionary Key. keys are unique. The same key can't appear twice in a dictionary, but different keys may point to the same value. All keys have to be of the same type, and all values have to be of the same type.

So as Leo commented, save 3 keys with the same value instead of a single array with 3 keys:

```
let mRNAtoEnglish: [String : Character] =
    ["UUU": "A",
     "UAC": "A",
     "UUA": "Q",
     "UUG": "Q",
     "UCU": "S",
     "UCC": "S",
     "UCA": "S"]
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer, however @Code Different's answer allows me to convert the dictionary to a class variable and save memory, and experiment with higher order functions (coming from a Java background, these things are still new to me, haven't gotten around to using them in my current CompSci class in version 8).

Thanks though!

Comment: More than saving memory, typing another literal dictionary increases your chance of making an error. And let's admit it: typing technical data is rather arduous.

Comment: @CodeDifferent The full dictionary contains a total of 64 codons! #thankknuthforcopyandpaste

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to write code to parse the first dictionary to produce the second, removing the opportunity for more typing errors.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a dictionary-based answer after all, this will produce the reversed version of `englishTomRNA`.

```
var englishTomRNA: [Character: [String]] = ["A": ["UUU", "UAC"],
                                            "Q": ["UUA"],
                                            "S": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA"]]

var mRNAtoEnglish = [String:Character]()
for (key, value) in englishTomRNA {
    for mRNA in value {
        mRNAtoEnglish[mRNA] = key
    }
}

print(mRNAtoEnglish)
// ["UUU": "A", "UCA": "S", "UCC": "S", "UAC": "A", "UUA": "Q", "UCU": "S"]
```

Comment: `englishTomRNA.forEach({(key, value) in value.forEach({mRNAtoEnglish[$0] = key}) })
`